# converting part of a text file to list

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a tab-delimited text file of movies and actors.  The entries are in the following format:

```
The Shawshank Redemption    ["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton", "William Sadler"]

The Dark Knight ["Christian Bale", "Heath Ledger", "Aaron Eckhart", "Michael Caine"]
```

Is there a simple way to have python treat the actor "list" as a python list data structure, rather than a string with `[` and `]` characters?  I've tried to write code to slice the string starting at the `[` character, strip the `[`,`]`, and `"` using `.strip()` and `.rstrip()`, then using `.split(' ,')` to make a list out of the remaining string. but that didn't return the results I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), the [**safer**](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) version of python's `eval()` function, which takes a string input and treats it as python code. Assuming there's always one tab stop, you can split with tabs `'\t'` just evaluate the second element:

```
import ast
for line in f.readlines():
    temp_list = ast.literal_eval(line.split('/t')[1])
    # do something
```

Just a breakdown, using your first line as example:

```
>>> first_line = "The Shawshank Redemption    ["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton", "William Sadler"]"
>>> split_line = first_line.split('/t')
>>> split_line
['The Shawshank Redemption', '["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton", "William Sadler"]']
>>> best_list_ever = ast.literal_eval(split_line[1])
>>> best_list_ever
["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton", "William Sadler"]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the eval() function, why is this safer?

Comment: @Mike see the link. In short, `eval` will evaluate absolutely anything, including os.system('rm -rf /') (DON'T DO THIS) which will literally start deleting all of your files. Of course, on a tiny python script saved locally on your computer, there's not very much chance of that happening, but it's good programming practice to use `literal_eval` anyways. The only difference between the two is that `literal_eval` will only evaluate valid python data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, after reading those docs, it makes perfect sense.  ALSO, my new default list variable has officially become "best_list_ever"

Comment: @Mike While it's not exactly efficient, it's definitely stylish.